# NSCollectionView implementation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-observing, key-value-coding, nscollectionview

I have looked at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CollectionViews/Introduction/Introduction.html) yet I still haven't successfully implemented a CollectionView. Here is what I have.

My KVO/KVC compliant NSMutableArray.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ProjectModel.h"

@interface KVOMutableArray : NSMutableArray

@property NSMutableArray* projectModelArray;

- (id)init;
- (void)insertObject:(ProjectModel *)p inProjectModelArrayAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)removeObjectFromProjectModelArrayAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)setProjectModelArray:(NSMutableArray *)a;
- (NSArray*)projectModelArray;

@end
```

ProjectModel.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ProjectModel : NSObject {
    NSString *applicationName;
    NSString *projectPath;
    NSImage  *image;
}

@property(retain, readwrite) NSImage  *image;
@property(retain, readwrite) NSString *applicationName;
@property(retain, readwrite) NSString *projectPath;
@end
```

ProjectModel.m:

```
#import "ProjectModel.h"

@implementation ProjectModel

@synthesize image;
@synthesize projectPath;
@synthesize applicationName;

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"xcodeproject.png"];
    return self;
}

@end
```

I also put `@property KVOMutableArray *projectsManager;` in my AppDelegate.h file and

```
projectsManager = [[KVOMutableArray alloc] init];
ProjectModel *pm1 = [[ProjectModel alloc] init];
pm1.projectPath = @"path here";
pm1.applicationName = @"Crittercism Example App";
[projectsManager addObject: pm1];
```

in my awakeFromNib method.
I get the following exception and then it terminates:

```
[<NSCollectionViewItem 0x1001c2eb0> addObserver:<NSAutounbinderObservance 0x1001e2a20> forKeyPath:@"representedObject.applicationName" options:0x0 context:0x103111690] was sent to an object that is not KVC-compliant for the "representedObject" property.
```

Not sure what is the problem. Any help is appreciated I know I've written a lot here.

[image: Nib file]

**Edit--**
The problem seems to be that it can't find representObject.image or any of the other properties for that matter. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: I would like to know why I am getting a -1?
The Documentation said I only needed 4 methods when I actually needed more than 4 methods...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked after I implemented these methods (turns out the documentation lied about only needing the 4 methods they suggested there):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ProjectModel.h"

@interface KVOMutableArray : NSMutableArray {
    NSMutableArray *projectModelArray;
}
@property (readonly, copy) NSMutableArray* projectModelArray;

- (id)init;
- (void)insertObject:(ProjectModel *)p;
- (void)insertObject:(id)p inProjectModelArrayAtIndex:(NSUInteger )index;
- (void)removeObjectFromProjectModelArrayAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)setProjectModelArray:(NSMutableArray *)array;
- (NSUInteger)countOfProjectModelArray;
- (id)objectInProjectModelArrayAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)insertProjectModelArray:(NSArray *)array atIndexes:(NSIndexSet *) indexes;
- (NSArray *)projectModelArrayAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes;
- (NSArray*)projectModelArray;
- (void)removeProjectModelArrayAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes;
- (NSUInteger)count;
- (void)insertObject:(id)object atIndex:(NSUInteger)index;

@end
```

Comment: Why a I getting downvoted... I am letting people know that the documentation was wrong...

Comment: the documentation is indeed wrong. I implemented my own KVOMutableArray and I found the same lie (https://github.com/haifengkao/KVOMutableArray).

Answer (score 0):

Set the mode of your array controller `Class` and the class name to `ProjectModel`